# How is the system described novel in any way? It is simply a proxy registration that has been digitzed.

Tags: patentability, novelty

In reference to the patent: [US7130878](https://www.google.com/patents/US7130878)

Answer (score 0):

When assessing patent claims, one thing you always need to consider is the priority date, which in this case is 2002-08-30. This means that you can compare patent claims only with information what was publicly available until the priority date.

Answer (score -1):

I am not a lawyer nor a software engineer, but in essence I agree with you. This is a patent that predates the [Bilski v. Kappos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilski_v._Kappos) and [Alice Corp. v. CLS Bank International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Corp._v._CLS_Bank_International) decisions. In particular looking at the first claim, I see vague descriptions of what is done rather than how things are done. I question whether such a patent would be issued now or if it is enforceable, but as I said, I'm not an attorney and can't comment authoritatively on that.

Comment: Yet another down voter who doesn't leave a comment why. I'm happy to improve my answers, but if I don't know what you object to, I have a harder time doing it.

Comment: It wasn't me, but I think your answer is rather vague and not really answering the question. Admittedly, the question is .... Anyways, the part that's novel might be the "proxy" thing, allowing anonymous domain registration. A discussion whether that's patentable over Alice and Co would certainly be intersting, but it doesn't answer the question asked. This should probably be a discussion in chat, if op were reachable. As is, I don't think adding complications to one liner questions really benefits anyone. I know you're trying to help the op, but let them help themselves ask a good question.

Comment: @DonQuiKong The answer is likely not answerable. What I wrote regarding Bilsky and Alice is highly relevant. Several of my answers have been down voted in the last week or so without a single comment why.